# Images changes when UICollectionView is scrolled

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

Im using a UICollectionView  to load images.

Following is my code.  ImageArray will contain the url for each images that has to be loaded. and In my code, Im trying to give a round border around the entire collectionview

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImageView *recipeImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];

    CALayer* layer = cell.layer;

    [layer setCornerRadius:4.0f];
    [layer setBorderColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.8 alpha:1].CGColor];
    [layer setBorderWidth:1.0f];


    if ([ImageArray count] >0){

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^(void) {
                NSData *data0 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:[ImageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
                UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: data0];

                dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
                    recipeImageView.image = image;
                });
            });

    }

    [spinnerShow stopAnimating];

    cell.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
    cell.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;

    return cell;
}
```

The problem that im facing is that,

1. The images contents are changing if im scrolling it horizotally
2. The round border is being rendered to each cells of collectionview but not the round border is not being rendered to the entire UICollectionView.

How can I sort this out?

Comment: Use SDWebImage, https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Comment: For your second question, you assign the layer of your cell to `layer`, that's why the border is not being rendered to the entire UICollectionView.

Comment: how can I be able to show it to the entire UICollectionView? Thank you

Comment: Not familiar with Obj-c, I think you should do something like this: `CALayer* layer = collectionView.layer`. Then round it as you do with the cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UICollectionView` will reuse the existing cell. So there might be a possibility that your `imageView` in `collectionViewCell` will display the previous loaded image.

Its not a perfect solution, but give a try like passing `nil` or default image to `imageView` before starting downloading like

```
recipeImageView.image = nil;
```

before

```
if ([ImageArray count] > 0) {
```

Answer (score 1):

in `UICollectionViewCell` is a method `prepareForReuse` which you should override and set `UIImageView`'s image to `nil`

Answer (score 0):

You can set border and corner radius to collection view like,

```
  collectionView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
  collectionView.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.8 alpha:1].CGColor;
  collectionView.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0f;
```

And don't set it in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`. Set it in `viewdidload`, so that it loads once, otherqwise it will set everytime when cell will deque!

Second thing, as suggest in one comment you should use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) for caching the images.

Make sure you set right constraints if you are using autolayout.

Hope this will help :)

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing the cell's tag but all cells have the same tag value of 100. This means that you are going to get unpredictable results and this is why your images keep changing.